# c# ODP.NET v112040 - invoking function returning table of object

Tags: c#, function, oracle11g, odp.net, user-defined-types

I have this function defined in a package specification:

```
FUNCTION get_int_tarefas ( id_clientes IN pv_structure_id_array, id_pedidos IN pv_structure_id_array, id_projetos IN pv_structure_id_array, inicio IN DATE, fim IN DATE) RETURN Z_INT_TAR;
```

Also in PKS I have:

```
TYPE pv_structure_id_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
```

The type returned by the function is declared  outside the package, in the DB objects

```
   create or replace
   TYPE Z_INT_TAR FORCE
    IS TABLE OF z_obj_inv_tar;

create or replace
TYPE z_obj_inv_tar FORCE AS OBJECT
(
  ID                        NUMBER(38,0) ,
  ID_PROJETO                VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  PROJETO                   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ID_TAREFA                 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  TAREFA                    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ID_CLIENTE                VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  CLIENTE                   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ID_PEDIDO                 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  PEDIDO                    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ID_ORDEM                  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  ORDEM                     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  DATA_INICIO               DATE,
  DATA_FIM                  DATE,
  PERIOCIDADE               NUMBER(38,0),
  AGREGA_AO_PEDIDO          CHAR(1),
  MOEDA                     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) ,
  PRONTO_A_FATURAR          CHAR(1),
  AUTOMATICO                CHAR(1) ,
  PLANEADO                  FLOAT ,
  REMANESCENTE              FLOAT ,
  FATURADO                  FLOAT,
  EMPRESA                         VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  ID_ENTIDADE_RESPONSAVEL VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
);
```

I'm trying, from c#, to invoke this function. Right now i'm not using the function is just making a select and cast multiset to the type Z_INT_TAR.
Somehow, i've not been able to find an example for this and get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_INT_TAREFAS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_INT_TAREFAS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_INT_TAREFAS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_INT_TAREFAS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

C# Code

```
    public static DataSet pesquisaInvoice(List<string> clientes, List<string> pedidos, List<string> projetos, DateTime inicio, DateTime fim)
    {
        OracleConnection conn;
        OracleCommand comm;
        DataSet ds;

        using(conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleBD"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using(comm = new OracleCommand("z_dti_invoice.get_int_tarefas", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                OracleParameter par_clt = new OracleParameter();
                //par_clt.ParameterName = "id_clientes";
                par_clt.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                par_clt.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                par_clt.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                par_clt.Value = clientes.ToArray();
                par_clt.Size = clientes.Count;

                OracleParameter par_ref = new OracleParameter();
                //par_ref.ParameterName = "id_pedidos";
                par_ref.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                par_ref.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                par_ref.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                par_ref.Value = pedidos.ToArray();
                par_ref.Size = pedidos.Count;

                OracleParameter par_prj = new OracleParameter();
                //par_prj.ParameterName = "id_projetos";
                par_prj.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                par_prj.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                par_prj.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                par_prj.Value = projetos.ToArray();
                par_prj.Size = projetos.Count;

                OracleParameter par_inicio = new OracleParameter();
                //par_inicio.ParameterName = "inicio";
                par_inicio.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Long;
                par_inicio.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                par_inicio.Value = inicio;

                OracleParameter par_fim = new OracleParameter();
                //par_fim.ParameterName = "fim";
                par_fim.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Long;
                par_fim.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                par_fim.Value = fim;

                OracleParameter resultado = new OracleParameter();
                //resultado.ParameterName = "Z_INT_TAR";
                resultado.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
                resultado.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                comm.Parameters.Add(par_clt);
                comm.Parameters.Add(par_ref);
                comm.Parameters.Add(par_prj);
                comm.Parameters.Add(par_inicio);
                comm.Parameters.Add(par_fim);
                comm.Parameters.Add(resultado);

                conn.Open();

                ds = new DataSet();
                OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: An associative array is also known as an "Index By Table". That's not what you have there. There's no Index By clause in your definition. Please read up on Index By Tables and redefine those parameters in your function correctly.

Comment: Also, you cannot bind to PL/SQL tables from client side applications. So you can't leave the PL/SQL as it is (a PL/SQL Table) and just change the ODP.NET side either. Try to modify the PL/SQL to be an actual associative array.